# Graphing $a=y(1-x)$ trendlines and sample

Tags: graphing-functions

I'd like to be able to express the following in a graph:

Given the equation $a=y(1-x)$ where $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$ and three class thresholds:

```
A: a<0.05
B: 0.05<a<0.1
C: a>=0.1
```

I'd like to show that the a sample $(y=1, x=0.7)$ falls under class C $(y=0.3)$ and under the class C curve.

How would I graph all 3 trendlines (classes) and the sample in a single graph in Excel or Python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you solve for $y=a/(1-x)$, then what you have are a family of plots indexed by $a$. So one way to do this is to sketch the curves with $a=0.05,0.1$ and then shade the areas between these curves. This is doable within Excel (see for instance [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/7018-excel-shade-area-between-two-lines.html) but may be more trouble than its worth. In python, it looks like Matplotlib has that functionality (see for instance [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-shade-the-regions-between-the-curves-in-matplotlib).)